# multithreading And Subscribe/Publish approach in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading, publish-subscribe

I understand that there is no multithreading support in javascript. And i wanted some expert advice on the below scenario..

My requirement is to perform  a AJAX call and upon successful completetion, i want to trigger set of events (to update the different parts of UI parallely)

- I am planned to use Subscribe/Publish pattern, is it possible to subscribe multiple listners to the AJAX completion event.
- If possible, i wanted to know how these listners notified on publish.. (parallely in muthithreaded way or one by one).

  And suggest me the best way to achive this one.. I really appreciate your thoughts.

**EDIT::**

I know there are popular frameworks like JQuery supports this pattern. But am in a situation to develop this functionality from a scratch (we have our own framework).

Comment: what Ajax framework do you use?

Comment: not really using any frameworks.. need to implement this in core js framework..  see my edits above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've a Request Pooler that might give you a good head-start here. [Since this answer was accepted I've retired the pooler in favor of a more complete "AJAX Helper" - the link has been updated.]

I'm not sure that'll do everything you want (although it sounds like it may be close).  It's old, but it works:

[Depressed Press DP_AJAX](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_ajax/)

It supports multiple simultaneous requests with timeout/retry, per-request handlers, has a very small footprint and can be combined with other code easily.

You create a pool (telling it how many simultaneous requests are allowed) and then toss requests at it.  When they're done they call whatever handler you specified.

A small, complete example of it's use:

```
        // The handler function
function AddUp(Num1, Num2, Num3) {
    alert(Num1 + Num2 + Num3);
};

    // Instantiate the Pool
myRequestPool = new DP_RequestPool(4);

    // Start the Interval
myRequestPool.startInterval(100);

    // Create the Request
myRequest = new DP_Request(
    "GET",
    "http://www.mysite.com/Add.htm",
    {"FirstNum" : 5, "SecondNum" : 10},
    AddUp,
    [7,13]);

    // Add the request to the queue
myRequestPool.addRequest(myRequest);
```

It's open source - feel free to chop/fold/spindle or mutilate it to your hearts content.

Jim Davis

Comment: thanks for sharing Jim, Its realling interesting one,, it seems the DP_requestpool will handle multiple AJAX reuests simultaneously... 

But in my context i wanted to fire multiple events parallely on the completion of single AJAX response...

Comment: Actually the same framework that allows you to launch several AJAX requests simultaneously should be easily adoptable to launching several of pretty anything simultaneously.

You modify the object from a specific request pool to a more general "statement pool" pretty easily I think.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://madskristensen.net/post/Simple-JavaScript-event-model.aspx) describes what you're trying to accomplish pretty closely. Essentially you just have a JavaScript file that holds an array of handlers/subscribers. Each subscriber registers itself with the publisher (i.e. gets added to the handlers array). Then in the onClose handler of your Ajax call, you'd call a function that iterates over the subscribers and notifies them each by name:

```
this.handlers = [];
...
 for(var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++)
  {
    this.handlers[i].eventHandler.call(this, eventArgs);
 }
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Yalestar.. it seems the given script calls the listeners in a seqution manner(one by one).. is there a way to simulate this to parallel one...

Answer (score 2):

Could this serve as a ligthweight message passing framework?

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.MessageQueues = {};

    this.PostMessage = function (Subject) {
        var Queue = this.MessageQueues[Subject];
        if (Queue) return function() {
                                        var i = Queue.length - 1;
                                        do Queue[i]();
                                        while (i--);
                                    }
        }

    this.Listen = function (Subject, Listener) {
        var Queue = this.MessageQueues[Subject] || [];
        (this.MessageQueues[Subject] = Queue).push(Listener);
    }
}
```

then you could do:

```
var myInstance = new MyConstructor();
myInstance.Listen("some message", callback());
myInstance.Listen("some other message", anotherCallback());
myInstance.Listen("some message", yesAnotherCallback());
```

and later:

```
myInstance.PostMessage("some message");
```

would dispatch the queues

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and you should really use a library for that to avoid all the browser incompatibilities. For example [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) provides Ajax functionality that lets you execute code on completion of the Ajax call. See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) for documentation.

Comment: not really using any frameworks.. need to implement this in core js framework.. see my edits above.. And this is going to be IE only app..

Comment: I'd still use a framework. It's just so much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fire functions in parralell use following:

```
this.handlers = [];
...
 for(var i = 0; i < this.handlers.length; i++)
  {
    setTimeout(function(){this.handlers[i].eventHandler.call(this, eventArgs);},0);
 }
...
```